# Counting the number of days in between in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two tables and one is the `LendTable` which contains `dateborrowed` and `datereturned` columns and the other one is the `PenaltyTable` which contains the `PenaltyAmount`.

To get the `PenaltyAmount`,  `datereturned` is subtracted from `dateborrowed`'.

So how can I get the value and bind it to `PenaltyAmount` column?

I m just new to programming in ASP.NET so help would be greatly appreciated. I've heard from my friends you can use 'Datediff'.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you seem to have a similar question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931928/counting-the-number-of-days-from-gridview-asp-net-c

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sorry about the repost might delete this soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datediff getting the date inbetween 2 dates and bind it to a gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057377/datediff-getting-the-date-inbetween-2-dates-and-bind-it-to-a-gridview)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like...

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["datereturned"]) - Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dateborrowed"]);
        ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("PenaltyAmountLable")).Text = ((ts.TotalDays) * Convert.ToDecimal(dr["PenaltyAmount"])).ToString();
    }
}
```