# Datediff getting the date inbetween 2 dates and bind it to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table with 'dateborrowed' and 'datereturned' column. What I want to do is I want to get the value in between 'datereturned' and 'dateborrowed' and bind it to another column in another table. Also how can I do it using datediff function? I'm still learning it in the meantime. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean get the value in between `datereturned` and `dateborrowed`? What result is when `datereturned = 01/01/2011 and dateborrowed = 01/01/2009` ? Please specify what result you want to get

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With C#.NET you can subtract one `DateTime` from another, resulting in a `TimeSpan`. For example:

```
TimeSpan timespan = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2011, 1, 1));
```

If you want a date in between two dates, you can then add half of this timespan to one of the dates:

```
TimeSpan timespan = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2011, 1, 1));
DateTime inBetween = DateTime.Now.AddDays(timespan.TotalDays / 2);
```

Answer (score 17):

```
TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["datereturned"]) 
            - Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dateborrowed"]);

(ts.TotalDays); // Will return the difference in Days
```