# how to calculate total days from starting date to end date in c#,.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i m making a project in which i have to calculate total number of days from starting date to ending date which are inserted in text box by user at run time in asp.net c#.i have to do this on button_click event.how to do this?
i tried this-

```
protected void TextBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get date from first text box

    DateTime dold = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
    DateTime dnew = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox14.Text);
    TimeSpan daydif = (dnew - dold);
    double dayd = daydif.TotalDays;
    Label27.Text = dayd.ToString();
}
```

Comment: it is not giving correct result?

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057377/datediff-getting-the-date-inbetween-2-dates-and-bind-it-to-a-gridview

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int diffDays = (date1.Date - date2.Date).Days;
```

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with two textbox changes

private void frm_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                calculatedays();
            }

```
        private void to_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            calculatedays();
        }

        public void calculatedays()
        {
            if (frm.Text == string.Empty) return;
            DateTime dt;
            DateTime.TryParse(frm.Text, out dt);

            if (frm.Text == string.Empty) return;
            DateTime dt2;
            DateTime.TryParse(frm.Text, out dt2);

            if (dt == DateTime.MinValue && dt2 == DateTime.MinValue) return;
            TimeSpan daydif = (dt2 - dt);
            double dayd = daydif.TotalDays;
            string s = dayd.ToString();
        }
```