# How to display popup message in the asp.net page only for certain days

Tags: asp.net, dialog, popup

I need to display pop up message on when loading the ASP.NET page. NOw I am using JQuery dialog to display information but the I need to show this dialog box only for certain days (max 30 days). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do all of it is client-side (subject of course to client side clock):

```js
var start = new Date(2015,2, 1); //start date March 1, 2015, toggle date to test

var diff = Math.floor((new Date() - start)/86400000);

if(diff < 30) {    
    alert("Popped because it has only been " + diff + " days");
} else {
    console && console.log("No alert, exceeded 30 days - it's been %o days", diff);
}
```

If you want server side/server time, then [refer to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6057432/304683) and trigger the alert (e.g. inject the js, a variable in the js, etc.)

Hth.