# Sum Column value in GridView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to SUM a date column in a Gridview. Please refer to my code. The complier errors - can not convert int to string.

Please advise.

Thanks

```
protected void GridViewFortNight_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            TimeSpan timeSpent = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                timeSpent += TimeSpan.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TimeSheetDayTotal"));
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = timeSpent.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm");
            }

        }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057377/datediff-getting-the-date-inbetween-2-dates-and-bind-it-to-a-gridview

Comment: Split the minutes on the `:`, convert to integer and divide the sum of all the values through 60. If you need seconds also just do the same and add them to the minutes in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

you have add a label in gridview footer.
Gridview row update event you have calculate it.
i hope you understand it.